# Creating a dynamic user interface?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'm primarily a backend developer, but I'm being put into front-end design.  I'm building just one panel(form) in an application.  I'll have to dynamically add/remove other items from the form based on what the user chooses for previous parameters.  For example, there will be a customer dropdown at the top of the panel. I need to be able to configure which other dropdown menus will display once the user makes a selection.  I will have a minimum of 90 different configurations.  Each configuration will have somewhere around 50 parameters.  What is the best way to handle this situation in C#?

Someone at my company suggested using a new form for each configuration, on SO I've seen people say to use user controls, and somewhere else said to dynamically put the controls in a list and generate content that way.  Some of these suggestions seemed counter-intuitive...

Can someone suggest a "proper" way to do this?  To put this in perspective, I've only ever built one form before, and it was very simple.  (This is a desktop application using .net 4.0)

Edit: This is in Winforms

Comment: Since you closed this, that must mean you seem to think no one else would ever have to customize a single panel with changing information?  I find this surprising. I would have thought there was some sort of best practice for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this WinForms or WPF?

Anyway, any thing you do in designer, you can do at run time in your code. Adding controls is just creating new objects and assigning properties:

WinForms:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Name = "Dynamic Button";
btn.Id = "DynButton"
btn.Width = 50;
btn.Click = {...};
[...]
panel.Controls.Add(btn); // panel is a parent container control. You have to have a parent for you button.
```

etc.
WPF is virtually the same - controls, parents, containers etc.

In your case you may have set of initially hidden panels with all the things inside, and show/hide them depends on your flow logic.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When designing a form requiring a large number of components there are various methods you can use that will get the desired result as you are finding out. Looking at some of the possibilites...

Method 1: Creating Seperate Forms for each configuration

This is not a bad idea because after the user makes the selection you can create a new instance of the desired form, but setting up all the individual forms will take some time, but is not difficult.

Method 2: Creating Multiple Panels for each configuration

This works similiar to method one except you would hide all the panels initially and then display the panel the user selects. You can either create the panels ahead of time and just hide or display, or you could do it programmatically at runtime. (Kinda non-proper to have numerous panels  full of components hiding in my opinion if you do the panels non-programmatically)

Method 3; Programmatically creating required components

You could just write code to generate the desired components based on the users selection.

Example:

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    ComboBox selection1 = new ComoboBox();
    selection1.Location = new Point(XXX,YYY); //Set location
    //You can add the events for the combobox, set up the properties 
    form1.Controls.Add(selection1); //Add the component to the form or panel that you want it displayed on

    //Write code to dynamically create next object(s)....
}
else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    //Programmatically create components for selection2
}
```

Of these I think Method 1 would be the easiest because it's just placing the components on a form, however this will be time consuming. Programmatically would probably be the most elegant in my opinion, as long as you keep the code well organized for the different possibilites and you don't have numerous forms or panels to deal with. You'd only be messing with the components. However when creating components programmatically assigning the properties can be time consuming as well.

I am not 100% sure on what the most formal approach for doing this is, but these are just some ideas.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not being much of a C# guy, I'm not going to be able to give you example code, but based on past experience, it sounds like what you are looking for is the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

The Decorator pattern will let you dynamically create your objects at run-time rather than compile time. You can use this to create your forms/buttons/whatever as needed by whatever is previously entered.